# Erro no NetworkInfo

Tags: android, internet, redes

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu tenho um metodo que verifica se o aparelho esta conectado a internet ou não

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    assert cm != null;
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting() && activeNetwork.getState() ==  NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
    return  isConnected;
}
```

Só que, quando eu estou conectado a uma wifi, onde ela não possui internet, ele retorna true. Ou seja, o método retorna true se existir conexão e não especificamente com a internet. Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ConnectivityManager realmente não consegue verificar a conexão com a internet. A solução mais simples é realizar um ping em alguma URL.

Com base [nesta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918248/android-internet-connectivity-check-better-method)
é possível verificar a conexão com a internet realizando um ping no DNS do Google da seguinte forma:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable(int timeoutMs) {
    Socket sock = new Socket();
    try {

      SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);
      sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs); // This will block no more than timeoutMs

      return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return false; 
    }finally{
      sock.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu tinha visto essa solução, só que ela não funciona para aparelhos, mais antigos, mas mesmo para minha realidade funciona muito bem.